# ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a customer who gets: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables:

Log show error Massage Error (30926)

```
13:52:19 (00:00:02.406) ERROR : Error (30926) (00:00:02.406) ORA-30926: Stabile Zeilengruppe in den Quelltabellen kann nicht eingelesen werden
TS03_MIN0100: UpdTable failed. Update inv_value in cMinTimeTable:
MERGE INTO HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005400223 a USING ( SELECT DISTINCT a.inv_value + 
( a.inv_value_sum - h.inv_value ) AS inv_value , a.rowid xzfd_rid 
FROM HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005700223 h , HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005400223 a 
WHERE a.voucher_no = h.voucher_no AND a.sequence_no = h.max_seq_no 
AND a.client = h.client ) xzfd_t ON ( xzfd_t.xzfd_rid = a.rowid ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE 
SET a.inv_value = xzfd_t.inv_value
```

I have checked for duplicate values in the tables but cant find anything unusual.
Maybe someone has an idea that could be useful.

The query is:

Query causing error (temp table):

```
INSERT INTO HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005700228 ( agg_flag , ace_code , activity , category , client , cost_dep , description , dim1 , dim2 , dim3 , dim4 , inc_ref , inv_value , max_seq_no , pd , period , project , resource_id , resource_typ , trans_date , unit , voucher_no , work_order , work_type )
SELECT agg_flag , ace_code , activity , category , client , cost_dep , description , dim1 , dim2 , dim3 , dim4 , inc_ref , SUM ( inv_value ) inv_value , max_seq_no , pd , period , project , resource_id , resource_typ , trans_date , unit , voucher_no , work_order , work_type
FROM HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005400228
WHERE agg_flag = 1
GROUP BY agg_flag , ace_code , activity , category , client , cost_dep , description , dim1 , dim2 , dim3 , dim4 , period , trans_date , voucher_no , max_seq_no , inc_ref , pd , project , resource_id , resource_typ , unit , work_order , work_type
```

Comment: Show us the query as well, as formatted text.

Comment: this kind of error pops up usually when there is more than one record matching the merge condition. So Oracle does not know which row to apply first.

Comment: I ran the follogin queries to look for duplicates:

select client, attribute_id, invoice_code, type, step_id 
from atsinvrules 
group by client, attribute_id, invoice_code, type, step_id 
having count(*) > 1 

On tables in question but found no duplicates.

Comment: It's not that clear to me. The error is about a MERGE, but you say that the query causing error is an INSERT. Can you please run the query in SQLPlus and post both the query and the error message?

Comment: ORA-30926 will only be triggered by a `MERGE` statement, not an `INSERT` statement

Comment: Here is a full detailed log file:
https://dc2.safesync.com/FgfcqGh/Detailed%20log%20file.txt?a=thKnYGGbUjM

Comment: Honestly, do you really think we will read more than 3000 log rows? Please open SQLPLus, run the query and post both the query and the error message, as text.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you creating/dropping tables instead of, say, creating a global temporary table (aka GTT) once and then using that to store your session level data? Saves the overhead of table creates/drops

Answer (score 2):

When you get that error, it will be from a MERGE statement, and it indicates that there are multiple rows in the source dataset that match to a row you're joining to in the target table, and as such, Oracle doesn't know which one to use to do the update.

Taking your merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005400223 a
USING (SELECT DISTINCT a.inv_value + ( a.inv_value_sum - h.inv_value ) AS inv_value,
                       a.rowid xzfd_rid 
       FROM   HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005700223 h,
              HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005400223 a 
       WHERE  a.voucher_no = h.voucher_no
       AND    a.sequence_no = h.max_seq_no 
       AND    a.client = h.client) xzfd_t
  ON (xzfd_t.xzfd_rid = a.rowid) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET a.inv_value = xzfd_t.inv_value;
```

it looks like the join between the two tables HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005700223 and HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005400223 in the xzfd_t subquery causes multiple rows to be returned for one or more of the HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005400223 rows (ie. you get multiple rows returned for at least one a.rowid).

To check this, run:

```
SELECT xzfd_rid,
       COUNT(*) cnt
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT a.inv_value + ( a.inv_value_sum - h.inv_value ) AS inv_value,
                        a.rowid xzfd_rid 
        FROM   HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005700223 h,
               HUBWBPMS5_ENTTS03005400223 a 
        WHERE  a.voucher_no = h.voucher_no
        AND    a.sequence_no = h.max_seq_no 
        AND    a.client = h.client)
GROUP BY xzfd_rid
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

In order to fix this, you'd need to make the xzfd_t subquery return a single row for each xzfd_rid. Possibly using row_number() to pick a single row, or an aggregate query to sum up all the h.inv_value fields per a.rowid instead of the DISTINCT.